NAT instance on Azure VM
I'm trying to setup a nat instance on azure for testing purpose but it isn't working at all.
I was able to create a nat instance using below steps on AWS. But I can't do the same thing in azure.
I tried the following settings on azure public subnet instance VM (10.0.0.6)
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
add "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" to sysctl.conf
sysctl -p

sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo /sbin/iptables -F FORWARD
sudo service iptables save

And in private subnet azure VM I tried adding a default route 0.0.0.0/0 to 10.0.0.6 IP.  Should I use route table instead?
But this isn't working. Private subnet VM can't ping google. I've allowed all IP in NSG as well.
Any idea why this isn't working? Also I can't find any articles on google about azure nat instance as if nobody has ever tried.

When you want to use your own router (and/or firewall) in Azure, you need to also tell Azure to route traffic through your VM.
For this, you need to enable IP forwarding on the VM NIC and to create and associate a User-Defined Route to the subnet.
This tutorial can help (although is a bit more complex than your scenario, it covers all the basics).
